# Java Alternative to C#'s WriteAttributeString()

Tags: java, c#, xml

In C#, there's a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmlwriter-writeattributestring(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string)) to write attributes to an XML element:

```c#
public void WriteAttributeString(string? prefix, string localName, string? ns, string? value);
```

What I have [found](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) in Java is:

```java
Attr createAttributeNS(String namespaceURI, String qualifiedName)
```

But it seems lacking two parameters. As far as I understand, `ns` == `namespaceURI`, and `localName` == `qualifiedName`.

Is there a similar method to achieve the same thing in Java? Or do I have to implement my own version (consequently, extending `Document`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could call [setAttributeNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) on org.w3c.dom.Element.

Suppose you want to generate an output like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <child xmlns:pfx="http://www.example.com" answer="42"/>
</root>
```

You could use something similar to the following code:

```
childElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:pfx","http://www.example.com");
childElement.setAttribute("answer", "42");
```

A complete, self-contained example might look like this:

```
package com.software7.test;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("root");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        Element childElement = document.createElement("child");
        rootElement.appendChild(childElement);
        childElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:pfx","http://www.example.com");
        childElement.setAttribute("answer", "42");

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

}
```